# Disabling a control based on checkbox state?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I want to disable the referenced control in the HTML and javascript below, yet it's not doing it. Seems simple enough. What could I be missing?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

    function Disable(isDisable, controlID) {
        var objControl = document.getElementById(controlID);

        if (objControl != null) {
            objControl.disabled = isDisable;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" id="form1">


<input name="date?4" type="text" value="1/1/2011 12:00:00 AM" id="date?4" runat="server" style="border-color:Black;font-family:Arial;width:300px;" 

/><input type="checkbox" style="font-family: Arial" onclick="Disable(this.checked, "date?4" );" >Disable
</form></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why does your input id have a question mark in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onclick is badly formatted:

```
onclick="Disable(this.checked, "date?4" );"
```

Use this instead:

```
onclick="Disable(this.checked, 'date?4' );"
```

If you use double quotes (`"`) as your attribute value delimiters, you can't use them inside the value without escaping them. You should use single quotes (`'`) inside.

Comment: D'oh!! Thanks for the quick reply!! That was it.

Answer (score 1):

Your string is broken in

```
onclick="Disable(this.checked, "date?4" );"
```

try with:

```
onclick="Disable(this.checked, 'date?4' );"
```

Additionally, according to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp), the '?' character is not valid in HTML ids.

Comment: Really? I've been using "?" in the ID's for a while now without issue. IN ie, Chrome and FF.

Comment: @user259286 I have never done it, but I had the doubt, searched it and found that page.

Answer (score 1):

You have double quotes in your onclick, so it's breaking the parsing. Change:
`onclick="Disable(this.checked, "date?4" );"`
to
`onclick="Disable(this.checked, 'date?4' );"`

I also had to drop the '?' in your id to get it to work in jsFiddle. Think some browsers might not like that.

Answer (score 0):

You are using " within a " enclosed attribute.